# WPF Update view in loop

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I'm using MVVM and when the model calculates a new background for a position it tells the viewmodel that it's changed. So what I want to do is update the view at every new background, but I think Thread.Sleep blocks the main UI thread.

```
private void New_Background(object sender, BackgroundEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
        {
            Fields[e.Position].Background = e.Background; //update this position's background at every step
            OnPropertyChanged("Background");
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }));
    }
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?
By the way, if I use MessageBox.Show(...) instead of Thread.Sleep, it updates the view at every messagebox.

Comment: *"...it tells the viewmodel that it's changed"*  Don't you think that your viewmodel could in turn also notify the view that it has changed, eliminating the need for event driven updates or timer driven loops?

Comment: That's why there's the "OnPropertyChanged("Background");" line, so the binding with the view works. The update actually works, but with Thread.Sleep, I think I'm blocking the UI thread so it doesn't update. I'm looking for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but I think Thread.Sleep blocks the main UI thread.

Yes, it does. The delegate that you pass to the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` method is being executed on the UI thread.

> how can I delay it so it gets slowed down a bit?

Slow down the loop:

```
private async void New_Background(object sender, BackgroundEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(async () =>
    {
        Fields[e.Position].Background = e.Background; //update this position's background at every step
        OnPropertyChanged("Background");
    }));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a higher [priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
DispatcherPriority.Send, 
new Action(() =>
        {
            Fields[e.Position].Background = e.Background; //update this position's background at every step
            OnPropertyChanged("Background");
        }));
```

Comment: The model uses an algorithm which calculates always the next step. The next step always has a new background picture. So at every new step, I want to update the view so that it shows the actual standing of the pictures, and not the standing before the algorithm started. Basically I want to update the view inside a loop.

Comment: @KollingMaster: Set a higher priority and see... See the updated answer.

Comment: This works, thanks. And now, how can I delay it so it gets slowed down a bit?

Comment: Await Task.Delay(50);

Comment: Making the Action async and then use await Task.Delay did not delay it.

Comment: 50 millisecond is pretty low try Delay(5000)

Comment: Still no change.